# How to send multiple computers a message with the msg command?

Tags: networking, command, msg

I want to send multiple computers a message with the `msg` command. This command is specific to windows/DOS.

I know these instructions:

> Send a message to a user.
>
> ```
> MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *} [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]
>
> username            Identifies the specified username.
> sessionname         The name of the session.
> sessionid           The ID of the session.
> @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
>                     sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
> *                   Send message to all sessions on specified server.
> /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
> /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
> /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
> /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
> message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
>                     or reads from stdin.
> ```

My question is: What is the structure of `@filename` and how to build it?

My network is Workgroup.

Comment: the @filename(names.txt) should have names separated with spaces or new line. example: john  mary 
This command is specific to windows/DOS, would be nice if you can mark the OS.

Comment: thanks for your answer.my windows is 10 enterprise..but when i edit @userlist.txt   with this structor  it says Input file userlist.txt names don't exist or are disconnected...while my user name in other computer is online and active...